# ASP NET MVC Eager Loading - Model is Null if no related records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Details page where I need to show lookup values that may be null.  I thought eager loading would get the record in such a case but it's not. Am I doing this wrong?

I've verified that a contract with no StatusID causes this to return no record

```
 public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
    {
        Contracts model = db.Contract
            .Include(x => x.Status)
            .Include(x => x.VendorName)
            .Where(x => x.ContractID == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (model == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

I was using this as guide for his "Offices" piece. I don't see why his returns rows even when an Office is null and mine does not: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Thanks for any smacks in the head.

Comment: Are `Status`/`VendorName` fields or foreign records? Eager loading has **no affect** on the record itself therefore the only reason for you to get `null` back is because there is no record matching the `ContractID`.

Comment: StatusID and VendorID are part of the Contracts table/model. Status is in the Status table, and VendorName is in the Vendor table

Comment: The relevant parts of the Contracts model are 
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public virtual Nullable<Guid> StatusID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public virtual Statuses Status { get; set; }

Comment: Your `Include` statement for `VendorName` just doesn't look right to me, I would expect `Include(x => x.Vendor.VendorName)`. Regardless, I think your `Where` statement is the problem, I'd double check your `id` parameter is correct.

Comment: That sort of syntax is what's used in the view. I.e., @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VendorName.VendorName) The id appears correct. A record is returned only when only lookups to other tables have a value

Comment: I'd probably rename the `VendorName` property on `Contracts` to `Vendor`, it's a bit more readable e.g. `model.Vendor.VendorName`. Hmm that would suggest that EF is generating an `INNER JOIN` when in fact you need an `OUTER JOIN` - so I might be wrong, the eager loading *might* actually affect the result.

Comment: See this [article](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/entity-framworks-include-function-produces-inner-joins-instead-of-outer-joins/)

Comment: Yes you seem to be correct, though after looking at that article I don't see what to do about it

Comment: The article would suggest that your relationship between `Status` or `Vendor` to `Contract` is `child -> parent` rather than `parent -> child`. Could you post your DB design?

Comment: In the Contracts model, both Status and Vendor are defined in this way public virtual Nullable<Guid> StatusID { get; set; } AND public virtual Statuses Status { get; set; } so it shouldn't think those are parents of Contracts.  And if Status can be null, there's no way it can be a parent of a Contract. What else would you want me to post?